# ¿Qué valor colocar en el content del http-equiv="Expires" para evitar caché?

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net

Estoy buscando que mi página no guarde los datos en la sesión, dado que hago muchas cosas con ayuda del JS pero cuando hago una modificación no la toma si no borro la caché, entonces he visto que si se utilizan las etiquetas meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

se debe arreglar, pero no estoy seguro si sí lo hace. Mi página es en ASP.Net y tambien leí que podía agregarle esto al `load` de las páginas y eso lo solucionaría:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(False)
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "private")
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
```

Mis preguntas:

1. ¿Qué valor se debe colocar en el `content="??"`: -1 ó 0?¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los valores?
2. ¿Así sí estaría evitando la caché, o lo que he colocado no sirve para nada?
3. ¿Cómo puedo verificar si está o no eliminando la caché? Es decir, quiero que siempre solicite la página como si fuera la primera vez que la consulta.

Comment: Además, ¿cómo puedo verificar si está o no eliminando el cache?, es decir, quiero que siempre solicite la página como si fuera la primera vez que la consulta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**¿Qué valor se debe colocar en el content="??": -1 ó 0?¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los valores?**

Supongo que te refieres a `<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />`, en cuyo caso, según la [documentación de W3C](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2068/rfc2068), el valor del `content` debería ser una fecha con el formato definido en el RFC 1123. Un ejemplo de este formato:

```
Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
```

Sobre poner -1 ó 0, en teoría no importa cuál de los dos porque serían equivalentes. Según la misma [documentación del protocolo HTTP/1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2068/rfc2068):

> HTTP/1.1 clients and caches MUST treat other invalid date formats,
>      especially including the value "0", as in the past (i.e., "already
>      expired").

Que se podría traducir como:

> En HTTP/1.1, los clientes y cachés DEBEN tratar otros formatos de fecha inválidos, especialmente incluido el valor "0", como en el pasado (i.e. "ya caducados").

Como tanto el 0 como el -1 serían fechas inválidas, se considerarían una fecha en el pasado y no guardar en la caché (así que se tratarían de igual manera). Aunque si la definición del protocolo menciona el valor "0" en particular, casi mejor usar ese directamente.

Pero cuidado: aunque teóricamente ponerle un valor de "0" debería funcionar, en esta otra [página de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13158_01/alui/wci/docs103/devguide/tsk_pagelets_settingcaching_httpexpires.html) se recomienda no hacerlo y en su lugar poner una fecha que esté en el pasado, porque si el tiempo de los servidores no está sincronizado, se podría devolver una versión *cacheada* por error.

---

**¿Así sí estaría evitando la caché, o lo que he colocado no sirve para nada?**

Lo que tienes debería ser más que suficiente, aunque podrías tener problemas con versiones antiguas de diferentes navegadores como se indica en los comentarios de esta [respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/3695983). Una cosa que podrías hacer para cubrirte las espaldas es duplicar cabeceras con los valores que sabrás que todos los navegadores admitirán de una manera u otra.

Entonces además de poner lo que ya tienes:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

podrías añadir alguna más (y ya de paso cambiar el valor de -1 a 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT" />
```

En esta [otra pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49547/3695983) puedes encontrar cómo se podría hacer en diferentes lenguajes de programación, así como información más detallada (aunque en inglés).

---

**¿Cómo puedo verificar si está o no eliminando la caché? Es decir, quiero que siempre solicite la página como si fuera la primera vez que la consulta**

Esto lo puedes comprobar en tu navegador cuando se carga la página, a través de las herramientas de desarrollo. Por ejemplo, en Chrome:

1. Abre las herramientas de desarrollador (pulsando <kbd>F12</kbd> o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
2. Pulsa en la pestaña de Red (*Network*)
3. Recarga la página
4. Podrás ver los diferentes elementos de la página y cómo se cargan:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   Si se cargan desde la caché, Chrome te lo podnrá en la columna de Tamaño (*Size*), como puedes ver en la imagen de arriba.