# No toma los cambios al generar archivos de publicación. Angular 8

Tags: c#, angular, iis

Tengo un proyecto en `angular 8` y `C#` `WebApi` el cual publico en un servidor `IIS`, hasta este punto todo bien, cuando realice la primera publicación no hubo problema pero Al momento de realizar cambios en mi aplicación y volver a generar los archivos, digamos al publicar la Versión 2, no toma los cambios realizados en mí `FrontEnd Angular` al ingresar a la aplicación, solo lo hace cuando recargo la página con **`ctrl + Shift + R`**.

Esto es un gran problema para los usuarios que utilizan la aplicación ya que si no recargan seguirán trabajando en la primera versión.

Esta es la forma en la que genero los archivos:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing=all
```

Esta línea me genera los siguientes archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo estas líneas de código en el `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

No sé que pasa pero solo toma la nueva versión solo si se recarga la página de esa forma.

**Edicion:**

Este es mi archivo **`WebConfig`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <!-- <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" /> -->
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
   <caching>         
       <profiles>
         <add varybyquerystring="*" location="Any"
           duration="00:00:01" policy="CacheForTimePeriod">
       </profiles>
     </caching>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Me gustaría que limpiara y forzara y la cache al momento de generar los archivos.

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto desde código o al generar los archivos ?

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45635/qu%C3%A9-valor-colocar-en-el-content-del-http-equiv-expires-para-evitar-cach%C3%A9

Comment: @PabloLozano agrego lo que dan en la respuesta , pero aun sigue sin funcionar lo actualiza con el  `Ctrl + shif + R`

Comment: En este link te muestran una solución bastante interesante, a través del hash de la aplicación verifica si ha cambiado y si es diferente entonces ejecuta la acción de reload o puedes mostrar una ventana notificando. https://blog.nodeswat.com/automagic-reload-for-clients-after-deploy-with-angular-4-8440c9fdd96c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configura el caching de tu IIS desde el web config de tu aplicación. Esto sobrescribirá cualquier configuración del Output Cache que tengas a nivel de servidor:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
       <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Puedes filtrar también por extensión para que se cacheen ciertos archivos estáticos.

Comment: Dentro de mi WebConfig, tengo esto `<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">` no hay ningun problema al agregar el `caching` ?

Comment: Las reglas de reescritura mantenlas también. Estas reglas son necesarias para que todas las urls vayan a index

Comment: Agrege el codigo, genere los archivos y al publicar me genera el error **`500 - Internal server error.`**  , Edite mi pregunta para que puedas ver el archivo webConfig

Comment: He editado el web config. Puedes hacer una prueba?

Comment: Dame un momento

Answer (score 1):

Este problema me ocurría frecuentemente con aplicaciones puestas en producción, y básicamente es debido al mecanismo de caché del navegador, hay diversas formas de lidiar con este problema desde el servidor diciendo al navegador cuál debe ser su política para el caché. Sin embargo una buena solución y que además te da otras ventajas es convertir tu aplicación en PWA, esto te permité enviar incluso un mensaje cuando hay una nueva versión de la aplicación disponible.

Esto se logra a través de la implementación de un Service Worker https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

El siguiente artículo me ayudó bastante a convertir y entender que es lo que hace una PWA https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/

En resumen podrías ejecutar:

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project <name of project as in angular.json>
```

Lo anterior convertirá tu aplicación a PWA y agregará algunos archivos de configuración, la CLI de Angular hará todo el trabajo. Luego de esto podrías hacer algo como esto en tu app.component.ts:

```
constructor(
    private swUpdate: SwUpdate
) {
    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {

        this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {

            if (confirm('New version available. Load new version?')) {

                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
```

El servicio que estás inyectando lo podrás importar luego de agregar @angular/pwa

```
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';
```

Espero pueda ayudarte, coméntame si tienes alguna duda al respecto, también puedes chequear los enlaces que te dejé arriba.

Comment: Aunque extenso tu aporte me parece más un comentario con algunos enlaces que una respuesta concreta en si, por favor lee [answer]

Comment: No hay una respuesta concreta para este tema, hay múltiples enfoques y los enlaces que referí responden exactamente este problema. Por favor lee acerca del tema y me disculpo si mi respuesta no fué adecuada.

Comment: El te esta haciendo una sugerencia en la cual deberías de editar tu pregunta, para no solo poner los enlaces ya que estos tienden a desaparecer, seria bueno un ejemplo de como implementar la solución.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta en espera de que pueda ser de ayuda. Cualquier duda o sugerencia es bien recibida.

Answer (score 0):

Es complicado este tema, en todos los sitios en los que he trabajado ya tenían este problema... Y sólo he visto una posible solución...
Y es poner una variable al final del include de modo que cada vez que esta cambie (en cada publicación) también cambiarán los archivos incluidos.

Pero ya te digo, los que ya están descargados, no se obtendrán por sí solos esta modificación, vas a tener que hacer algún cambio drástico que necesiten tener la última versión si o si.

Podrías probar, a poner el **app_offline.htm** en el IIS para poder hacer un reset, pero creo que todo cliente que no entre, no se refrescará la caché.

Te pongo un ejemplo de lo que menciono más arriba.

```
<script src="utilidades.js" />
```

Por:

```
<script src="utilidades.js?V=1.2" />
```

Espero que te haya ayudado con esto, un saludo!

Comment: A que include tendría que agregar la variable ?

Comment: Pues a todos los que tengas en el index.html (css y js, imágenes no recuerdo), además teniendo las variables para evitar el caché en los meta, te dejo un ejemplo:
`<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />`
`<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />`
`<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />`
`<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />`
`<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />`

Comment: He agregado a cada include la variable, toma perfectamente los cambios en los **css** y **js** pero no en los **Component** de **`Angular `**

Comment: Hace unos días vi un script que recorría los componentes... Imagino que con eso se podría ver, intentaré localizarlo y te lo hago llegar :)

Comment: Una pregunta tonta, en cada publicación limpias el directorio de publicación antes no? Porque las publicaciones de Angular, suelen generar los JS con nombres distintos
También se me ocurre.. Tener un código JS que obtenga todos las etiquetas <script con propiedad src, y añadirle la variable al final.. Ya me voy a dormir, si necesitas ayuda, mañana lo vemos